# Filter pandas dataframe with specific column names in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and a list as follows

```
mylist = ['nnn', 'mmm', 'yyy']
mydata =
   xxx   yyy zzz nnn ddd mmm
0  0  10      5    5   5  5
1  1   9      2    3   4  4
2  2   8      8    7   9  0
```

Now, I want to get only the columns mentioned in `mylist` and save it as a csv file.

i.e.

```
     yyy  nnn   mmm
0    10     5     5
1    9      3     4
2    8      7     0
```

My current code is as follows.

```
mydata = pd.read_csv( input_file, header=0)

for item in mylist:
    mydata_new = mydata[item]

print(mydata_new)
mydata_new.to_csv(file_name)
```

It seems to me that my new dataframe produces wrong results.Where I am making it wrong? Please help me!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just pass a list of column names to index `df`:

```
df[['nnn', 'mmm', 'yyy']]

   nnn  mmm  yyy
0    5    5   10
1    3    4    9
2    7    0    8
```

---

If you need to handle non-existent column names in your list, try filtering with `df.columns.isin` -

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(['nnn', 'mmm', 'yyy', 'zzzzzz'])]

   yyy  nnn  mmm
0   10    5    5
1    9    3    4
2    8    7    0
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. However, it is a typo. I corrected it. Btw, I want to loop over than directly mentioning the columns heading as my real data list is very long. Is there any special way of doing it?

Comment: @JCena this might surprise you, but it's faster to select them all at once.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The reason why I said was some of the column heading names in `mylist` is not actually in my dataframe. So I get an error like this `KeyError: "['recipe' 'food' 'calories' ..., ] not in index"`. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @JCena Indeed, there is. See my last edit. Happy coding!

Comment: If you need to handle non-existent column names, the [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) function provides a cleaner and shorter syntax than the `.loc[:, df.columns.isin()]` syntax proposed here. See my answer below for more details

Answer (score 5):

You can just put `mylist` inside `[]` and pandas will select it for you.

```
mydata_new = mydata[mylist]
```

Not sure whether your `yyy` is a typo.

The reason that you are wrong is that you are assigning `mydata_new` to a new series every time in the loop.

```
for item in mylist:
    mydata_new = mydata[item]  # <-
```

Thus, it will create a series rather than the whole df you want.

---

If some names in the list is not in your data frame, you can always check it with,

```
len(set(mylist) - set(mydata.columns)) > 0
```

and print it out

```
print(set(mylist) - set(mydata.columns))
```

Then see if there are typos or other unintended behaviors.

Comment: You're missing the fact that there's a (possible) "typo" in the column names.

Answer (score 1):

If `mylist` contains some column names which are not in `mydata.columns`, you will get an error like

```python
KeyError: "['fff'] not in index"
```

In this case, you can use the [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) function:

```python
mydata.filter(['nnn', 'mmm', 'yyy', 'fff'])
```