# Pandas filter a list of items present in a column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe like as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["Hi how","I am fine","Ila say Hi"],
                   'tokens':[['Hi','how'],['I','am','fine'],['Ila','say','Hi']],
                    'labels':[['A','B'],['C','B','A'],['D','B','A']]})
```

I would like to do the below

a) Filter the df using `tokens` AND `labels` column

b) Filter based on the values `Hi`, `Ila` for tokens column

c) Filter based on the values `A` and `D` for labels column

So, I tried the below

```
df[((df['tokens']==['Hi'])&(df['tokens']==['Ila']))&((df['labels']==['A'])&(df['labels']==['D']))]
```

However, this doesn't work.  Since my column has values in `list format`, how do I filter them whether the list has only one item or multiple items?

I expect my output to be like as below

```
text          tokens             labels
Ila say Hi   [Ila, say, Hi]      [D, B, A]
```

Comment: Take your pick: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-filter-by-column-value/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198021/filter-pandas-dataframe-with-specific-column-names-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71050756/how-to-plot-a-pandas-dataframe-by-filtering-a-column

Comment: Sorry. None of this helps. because they all show normal filtering of a value in a dataframe. But I want to filter a value that is present in list format in a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
df.loc[
    df['tokens'].apply(lambda x: 'Hi' in x) &
    df['tokens'].apply(lambda x: 'Ila' in x) &
    df['labels'].apply(lambda x: 'A' in x) &
    df['labels'].apply(lambda x: 'D' in x) 
]
```

Output

```
         text          tokens     labels
2  Ila say Hi  [Ila, say, Hi]  [D, B, A]
```

You could also cast to string and use:

```
df.loc[
    df['tokens'].astype(str).str.contains('Hi') &
    df['tokens'].astype(str).str.contains('Ila') &
    df['labels'].astype(str).str.contains('A') &
    df['labels'].astype(str).str.contains('D') 
]
```